# How do i create a listview object Android

Tags: android, listview

Hi so what im trying to do is when the player loses the game a highscore list comes up taking up half the screen in the form of a listView. Im trying to work with a listview object inflated from my xml im not sure how to do this though.

I have tried:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.id.highscores,null);
```

but it keeps telling me lv is null

heres my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.SpaceShot.single android:id="@+id/single1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </com.SpaceShot.single>

<ListView android:id="@+id/highScores"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:padding="15dp"
 android:visibility= "invisible"
 >
</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT:

Now inflating the ListView works but i get this error:

```
03-15 23:05:01.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-11 
exiting due to uncaught exception
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555): android.view.InflateException: Binary
 XML file line #9: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:564)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
com.SpaceShot.single$singleThread.doDraw(single.java:503)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
com.SpaceShot.single$singleThread.run(single.java:1754)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555): 
Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555): at com.SpaceShot.single.<init>
(single.java:1922)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at     
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     ... 7 more
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555): 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at android.os.Handler.<init>
(Handler.java:121)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at android.view.SurfaceView$1.
<init>(SurfaceView.java:107)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>
(SurfaceView.java:105)
03-15 23:05:01.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2555):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: r u loading the correct layout in the activity?

Comment: Can you show the code where you get your inflater?

Comment: So you are getting an error when you inflating the listview?

Comment: my errors a nullpointer on listview and i added the inflater code. also incase this makes any difference im doing this inside of my single class and i have already inflated the xml singleplayer in my activity once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LayoutInflater is used to inflate a layout , so you need to do the following to get the correct result:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);

ListView v = (ListView)layout.findViewById(R.id.highscores);
```

Comment: thank you now im getting a different error though ill post in my original post

Comment: For your 2nd issue, as you can see from the stacktrace that issue probably is caused by that custom view, you may need to post some of your code in that class in order to tackle the issue ;)

Comment: its over 2000 lines the thing is though that it inflates without error when i do it in my activity

Comment: Please have a look into the codes around line 1922 in single.java.
From the stacktrace:  
"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".
Error Probably caused by this, hopes this help you

Comment: what is a invocation targetexception?

Comment: That means the method/view you invoke throws Exception.
You better start a new post instead of continue discussing here which is not good ;)